# How can I determine if an iPhone's Wi-Fi is switched on?

Tags: iphone, reachability, wifi

I'm not talking about actually communicating over Wi-Fi, so testing the reachability of a host is not applicable here.  iOS uses SSIDs to help geolocate you; you don't have to be connected to the Wi-Fi networks to gain that benefit, but you do have to have Wi-Fi activated on your phone.

I'd like to warn users that they'll get poor location data if they don't have Wi-Fi active and they're indoors.  Anybody know if this is possible?

Thanks!